# How can I group routes

Tags: laravel, routes, backend, laravel-9

```
Route::group(['controller' => [AdminController::class], 'middleware' => ['role:administrator']], function () {
    Route::get('/admin', 'index');
});
```

It doesn't recognize the AdminController

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::controller(AdminController::class)
    ->middleware('role:administrator'))
    ->group(function () {
        Route::get('/admin', 'index');
    });
```

More information about route controller groups in https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-group-controllers